# Getting rid of errors when running VSCode extension tests

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Observe:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/aida/helloworld [master ? +12 ~0 -0 !]$ npm run test

> helloworld@0.0.1 pretest
> npm run compile && npm run lint


> helloworld@0.0.1 compile
> tsc -p ./


> helloworld@0.0.1 lint
> eslint src --ext ts


> helloworld@0.0.1 test
> vscode-test

Found existing install in /home/mark/aida/helloworld/.vscode-test/vscode-linux-x64-1.85.0. Skipping download
[256695:1212/134628.015413:ERROR:node_bindings.cc(303)] Most NODE_OPTIONs are not supported in packaged apps. See documentation for more details.
[256695:1212/134628.216902:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(590)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.portal.Settings.Read: object_path= /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop was not provided by any .service files
[main 2023-12-12T18:46:28.397Z] update#setState disabled
[main 2023-12-12T18:46:28.398Z] update#ctor - updates are disabled by the environment
[256695:1212/134628.465162:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(702)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for redirector.gvt1.com failed:
----- Certificate i=2 (emailAddress=support@zscaler.com,CN=Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net),OU=Zscaler Inc.,O=Zscaler Inc.,ST=California,C=US) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found


[256729:1212/134628.466278:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(978)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
Via 'product.json#extensionEnabledApiProposals' extension 'ms-python.python' wants API proposal 'registerIssueDataProvider' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST. Likely, the proposal has been finalized (check 'vscode.d.ts') or was abandoned.
Loading development extension at /home/mark/aida/helloworld
[256695:1212/134629.185517:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(702)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for default.exp-tas.com failed:
----- Certificate i=2 (emailAddress=support@zscaler.com,CN=Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net),OU=Zscaler Inc.,O=Zscaler Inc.,ST=California,C=US) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found


[256729:1212/134629.185919:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(978)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
Started local extension host with pid 257008.

  Extension Test Suite
    ✔ Sample test
  1 passing (48ms)
[main 2023-12-12T18:46:30.234Z] Extension host with pid 257008 exited with code: 0, signal: unknown.
Exit code:   0
Done

mark@L-R910LPKW:~/aida/helloworld [master ? +12 ~0 -0 !]$
```

The extension is a vanilla one as created by `yo code`. The unit test is run and passes, but  there are some number of error messages, unaffecting the unit tests, but still annoying.

Is it possible to clean them?

A note about the ZScaler - its certificates are found in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and I do not have certificate issues in general.